# How to allow an Array to accept multiple types?

Tags: c#, arrays, inheritance

Sorry if dumb question, am new to programing
So, I have a couple of classes like:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    int a;
}
public class ChildClass1:BaseClass
{
    string b;
}
public class ChildClass2:BaseClass
{
    string c;
}
```

And I need an array to be able take any of these classes, how could I achieve that?

Tried making an array using the base class, but couldn't acess child classes data.

```
public BaseClass[] array = new BaseClass[20];
```

Comment: Use the list instead. new List<BaseClass> and then you can call `ToArray`

Comment: You can't access to child data because Child1 doesn't have same property as Child2. But both children have same A exposed. It is good for using design pattern IMHO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code *is valid*.

```
BaseClass[] array = new BaseClass[20];
array[0] = new BaseClass();
array[1] = new ChildClass1();
array[2] = new ChildClass2();
... // etc
```

and all the elements have access to the base class fields (`int a`). But to access the child classes you need some pattern matching

```
for(int i=0; i<array.Length; i++)
{
    BaseClass item = array[i];
    if(item != null )
    {
        Console.Write(item.a);
    }
    if(item is ChildClass1 child1)
    {
        Console.Write(child1.b);
    }
    if(item is ChildClass2 child2)
    {
        Console.Write(child2.c);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```